# Can't find configs/.h when make u-boot for beagle bone

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

I'm customizing u-boot for beagle bone black. I cloned u-boot git and checkout to v2015.07. When I ran make command, 
make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf-
It shows error like this:

```
/u-boot((HEAD detached at v2015.07))$ make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf-
```

> scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig   CHK
>   include/config.h   GEN     include/autoconf.mk In file included from
>   ./include/common.h:18: include/config.h:5:10: fatal error: configs/.h:
>   No such file or directory  #include 
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. scripts/Makefile.autoconf:72: recipe for target 'include/autoconf.mk'
>   failed make[1]: *** [include/autoconf.mk] Error 1

Did anyone get the same error like mine? Please help me solve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build U-Boot you first have to create file .config:

```
make omap3_beagle_defconfig
```

The next step is to actually build U-Boot.

```
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make
```

The current release of U-Boot is v2019.01 and compatible with GCC 6, 7, and 8.

I suggest you build a more current release than v2015.07.

Comment: And when I want to clean what I made, run make distclean. Is it correct?

Comment: `make mrproper` cleans up everything.